# Camera Crash on Zooms to max and tap capture in iphone 6 devices

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, ios8.3

I have use the `UIImagePickerController` in my app,
App crashes if the user zooms the image to the max and taps on capture icon (8.3 OS issue happening only in iPhone 6)

Below is the crash log:

> iPhone-6-39 ReportCrash[1481] : task_set_exception_ports(B07,
>   400, D03, 0, 0) failed  iPhone-6-39 ReportCrash[1481] :
>   ReportCrash acting against PID 1473 iPhone-6-39 ReportCrash[1481]
>   : Formulating crash report for process myapp[1473]